# Azure Function will not add specific dll to Bin folder

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, json.net

I am moving my code to a new machine but my code will not run correctly on the new machine.
Old machine will put the newtonsoft.json.dll into the debug/net48/bin folder.
New machine will not put the newtonsoft.json.dll int the debug/net48/bin folder.

Initially I moved my code to the new machine via git but that failed. Then I zipped up my code and copy and pasted it to the new machine where it too built but it too would not add the dll to the bin folder.

The project in question is a Azure Function v1.  V1 azure functions have a hard stop on its Newtonsoft Version to be 9.0.1. My project is still in Framework 4.8 due to not having time to convert to CORE. I made a work around for this issue a few years ago with some assembly binding redirect code.  I was able to update my Newtonsoft to version 13.  This has been working great.  But only one machine builds this correctly for deployment.

I do not have any code to show as its not a code issue.  There is something preventing the new machine from putting the newtonsoft.dll into the bin folder when the project is run. Because that dll is not bin the Binding Redirects will not work. I can still run the app from the old machine but I want to move and think its bit fragile to depend on that.

I have a portion of the output file that seems relevant here (its a few thousand lines due to an unrelated warning message showing up) :

```
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  RestSharp.dll
  RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson.dll
  SendGrid.dll
  Twilio.dll
  YamlDotNet.dll
'C:\Repo\MyJob\bin\Release\net48\bin\extensions.json' successfully written.
Done executing task "GenerateFunctionsExtensionsMetadata".
Task "Move" skipped, due to false condition; ($(_IsFunctionsSdkBuild) == 'true' AND 
Exists('$(TargetDir)extensions.json')) was evaluated as (true == 'true' AND 
Exists('C:\Repo\MyJob\bin\Release\net48\extensions.json')).
Done building target "_GenerateFunctionsExtensionsMetadataPostBuild" in project "MyJob.csproj".
Target "_FunctionsBuildCleanOutput" in file "C:\Users\Myname\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.2.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets":
Using "RemoveRuntimeDependencies" task from assembly "C:\Users\Myname\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.2.0\build\..\tools\net46\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.dll".
Task "RemoveRuntimeDependencies"
Task Parameter:OutputPath=C:\Users\Myname\source\repos\EsperantoAPI-JobEngine\MyJob\bin\Release\net48\bin
Done executing task "RemoveRuntimeDependencies".
Done building target "_FunctionsBuildCleanOutput" in project "MyJob.csproj".
Target "DotNetPublish" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(DeployOnBuild)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
Target "_PackAsBuildAfterTarget" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(GeneratePackageOnBuild)' == 'true' AND '$(IsInnerBuild)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true' AND '' != 'true').
```

Unrelated waring message in build that I am researching before I post here.
Could not determine whether the attribute type 'System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute' used in the assembly 'MyServiceCalls.dll' derives from 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.WebJobsStartupAttribute' because the assembly defining its base type could not be found. Exception message: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

The Assembly Redirect Code to handle the issue with NewtonSoft versions.  This works if the dll is added to the bin.

```
    public static class AssemblyBindingRedirectHelper
{

    ///<summary>
    /// Reads the "BindingRedirecs" field from the app settings and applies the redirection on the
    /// specified assemblies
    /// </summary>

    public static void ConfigureBindingRedirects()
    {
        var redirects = GetBindingRedirects();
        redirects.ForEach(RedirectAssembly);
    }

    private static List<BindingRedirect> GetBindingRedirects()
    {
        var result = new List<BindingRedirect>();
        var bindingRedirectListJson = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BindingRedirects");
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(bindingRedirectListJson)))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<BindingRedirect>));
            result = (List<BindingRedirect>)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void RedirectAssembly(BindingRedirect bindingRedirect)
    {
        ResolveEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            var requestedAssembly = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
            if (requestedAssembly.Name != bindingRedirect.ShortName)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var targetPublicKeyToken = new AssemblyName("x, PublicKeyToken=" + bindingRedirect.PublicKeyToken).GetPublicKeyToken();
            requestedAssembly.SetPublicKeyToken(targetPublicKeyToken);
            requestedAssembly.Version = new Version(bindingRedirect.RedirectToVersion);
            requestedAssembly.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= handler;
            return Assembly.Load(requestedAssembly);
        };
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += handler;
    }

    public class BindingRedirect
    {
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string PublicKeyToken { get; set; }
        public string RedirectToVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you referenz newtonsoft in the csproj? Is it also in the packeges.json?

Comment: Via nuget.  but I also tried doing it via an assembly reference by adding a folder with the dll to the project.

Comment: It seems that the new machine is not adding the Newtonsoft.Json.dll to the bin folder when the project is run. This could be due to a missing reference or a configuration issue. You mentioned that you have a work around for this issue with some assembly binding redirect code. Can you please provide more details on this code?


Also, have you tried manually adding the Newtonsoft.Json.dll to the bin folder on the new machine and see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: This warning message could be due to a missing reference or a configuration issue. You can try adding a reference to the 'System.ServiceModel' assembly in your project and see if that resolves the issue. If that doesn't work, you can try updating the version of the 'System.ServiceModel' assembly to match the version that is required by the 'MyServiceCalls.dll' assembly.

Comment: @RajeshM  I added the assembly redirect code for you to see.  But the issue is the Dll will not get put into the bin that is the real issue.